# What is the real meaning of 爸爸去哪儿?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The popular Chinese reality show gives its official translation for the above as "Where are we going, dad?"

But it should be "Where has dad gone?" or "Where is dad?" in my opinion.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: English speakers may feel there should be a comma after 爸爸: 爸爸,去哪儿, but otherwise official translation seems valid, cf. results of feeding １。where has gone, 2. where did go, 3.where going to jukuu: examples of responses: 1. “嘉莉上哪里去了？ “他去哪里了？2. 你们今天去了哪里？  “他去哪儿了呢？。3. 你去哪儿？  老兄，你到哪儿去？

Comment: @fefe Because there is no "we" in the original, nor a comma (,)given to indicate there is a pause and "we" are implied.

Answer (score 3):

爸爸去哪儿? sounds more like 爸爸(我们)(要)去哪儿? or 爸爸(你)(要)去哪儿?, while 爸爸去哪儿了 sounds like 'where has dad gone'.

Comment: Now it is a film about kids and dads, so it is what you say. But it also can mean what I mean, because there is no "us" as you say, and the punctuation mark is not provided. 爸爸，去哪儿？could be more sensible. If "we" could be skipped, then why not “了”？

Comment: It's because 了(indicating a completion) would change the original meaning from the sentence 爸爸去哪儿. A similar case in English, let's say, you say to someone: "Go!". It could mean either "we go" or "you go" depending on the context.  You just omit the subject in that case.